# How to handle the exception?

Tags: c++, exception

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class test
{
    public:
        test()
        {
            cout<<"hello";}
            ~test()
            {
                cout<<"hi";
                throw "const";
            }
            void display()
            {
                cout<<"faq";
            }
};
int main()
{
    test t;
    try{
    }
    catch(char const *e)
    {
        cout<<e;
    }
 t.display();
}
```

output:[image: output:]

i know by throwing exception from destructor i'm violating basic c++ laws but    still i want to know is their any way the exception can be handled.

Comment: So, aside from this small example, what are you really trying to accomplish? Because it feels like you're doing it wrong...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your destructor runs outside the `try`-`catch` block - `t`'s scope is the `main` function. but then raising exceptions from a destructor is a **[Bad Idea<sup>TM</sup>](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.9)**.

Comment: i cannot declare test t in try block as i want t.display to execute as well.

Comment: Put call to `display()` within the `try`-`catch` too?

Answer (score 3):

The creation of your test object must be done inside the try block:

```
try
{
 test t;
 t.Display();
}
```

and a full version:

```
 #include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class test
{
    public:
        test()
        {
            cout << "hello" << endl;
        }

        ~test()
        {
            cout << "hi" << endl;
            throw "const";
        }
        void display()
        {
            cout << "faq" << endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        test t;
        t.display();
    }
    catch(char const *e)
    {
        cout << e << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: i cannot as i want t.display to execute too.

Comment: Ok, I added the call to Display().

Comment: Check this version. It displays "hello", "faq", "hi" and "const".

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing in your try block. Try this:

```
try
{
    test t;
}
catch(char const *e)
{
    cout << e;
}
```

Also, in general throwing an exception in a destructor is a bad idea (as with most rules, there are exceptions).

Comment: i cannot as i want t.display to execute too. By using try
{
    test t;
}
i'm making t local to try block and this will pop error.

Comment: @desprado07: Put the call to display in the try-block too.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just call the destructor function explicitly in try block?